# memset used with zero length parameter: ignore or watch out?

Tags: c++, warnings

I'm having trouble finding any information regarding the following warning when linking a dynamic library:

```
In function `MyClass::myfunc()':
MyClass.cpp:(.text+0x14e4): warning: memset used with constant zero length parameter; this could be due to transposed parameters
```

Here is an excerpt of `myfunc`:

```
void MyClass::myfunc() {
    vector<Variable*>::const_iterator it;

    for (it = m_vars.begin();
         it != m_vars.end();
         ++it) {
        if ((*it)->recordme) {
            MyRecord* r = new MyRecord(*it);
            initMyRecord(*r);
            m_records.push_back(r);
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm pretty much stuck on were should I be looking for possible causes for this memset. The call to the new operator is my first suspect, but I'm not even sure if it's worth looking for this. I'm not sure either if I should take this warning seriously or let it pass.

Question: what should I do about this warning? And what kind of patterns should I look out for in order to assure that I'm not going to shoot myself in the foot later?

Update:
Here is the MyRecord constructor, which is in a header file, so it might or might not be inlined, if I understand correctly.

```
class MyRecord {
public:
    MyRecord(const Variable* var) :
        buffer(0),
        lastSave(-1 * std::numeric_limits<double>::max()),
        sample(100),
        bufsize(100),
        gv(var),
        rec_function(0)
    {};
    virtual ~Record() {
        if (rec_function)
            delete rec_function;
        rec_function = 0;
    };

private:
    Record(const Record&);
    Record& operator=(const Record& rec);

public: // @todo: remove publicness
    boost::circular_buffer< boost::tuple<double,boost::any> > buffer;
    double lastSave;
    double sample;
    unsigned int bufsize;
    const Variable* gv;
    RecordFunctor* rec_function;
};
```

The RecordFunctor is a pure-virtual struct:

```
struct RecordFunctor {
    virtual ~RecordFunctor() {};
    virtual void record(const double) = 0;
};
```

Additional info? I'm compiling with flags `-O2` and g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1

Comment: what's happening in the MyRecord constructor and that initMyRecord() method?

Comment: What about `initMyRecord()`? Is that `inline`? Does it call `memset()`?

Comment: comment out each line in the above function and check if the warning is disappearing. So, you can isolate the problem step by step

Comment: I edited the question to add the code of the constructor. I ommited the `initMyRecord` function because I have pinned the problem down to the constructor.

Comment: Your `MyRecord` constructor is passing `0` to the constructor of `boost::circular_buffer`.

Comment: You can disable optimization (`-O0`) and if that doesn't narrow things down, you can look at the assembler output (`-S`) and try to see whether that gives any indication about the context of the memset call.

Comment: *Aside*: your destructor should just be : `virtual ~Record() { delete rec_function; }`. All of the others bits are superfluous and redundant. And redundant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are calling the [`boost::circular_buffer` constructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html#classboost_1_1circular__buffer_18f1606a26fead923c2cbe068a74e28b6) with a `capacity` of 0. This probably causes that constructor to call `memset()` to initialise the storage used by the circular buffer, but you've told it you want a buffer of zero size.

The solution is to give the `circular_buffer` constructor the actual size you want, not zero (zero doesn't make sense).

Answer (score 20):

The behavior of the `memset()` function with a size of `0` is well defined, as long as the pointer argument is valid.

See section 7.21.1 of the C99 standard, or 7.24.1 of the C11 standard:

> Where an argument declared as **size_t n** specifies the length of the
> array for a function, n can have the value zero on a call to that
> function.

On the other hand, the warning is a sensible one; a call like `memset(s, 0, 0)` is not dangerous, but it's not useful (it does nothing), and could easily indicate a programming error.

[Greg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11402350/827263) explains how to avoid it in this case.