# bits/string3.h:82: warning: memset used with constant zero length parameter

Tags: mysql, c, api

This is my MCVE using MySQL C API:

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main()
{
    mysql_init( NULL );
}
```

Compiling with `gcc 4.9.3 -O3 -I /usr/include/mysql` produces this warning:

```
/usr/lib64/mysql/libmysqlclient.a(ssl.cpp.o): In function `memset':
/usr/include/bits/string3.h:82: warning: memset used with constant zero length parameter;
         this could be due to transposed parameters
```

**Environment:**

Using `MySQL 5.7.13 Server` and `C API 6.1.6` on `SLES 12 SP1` VM on `XenServer`.

**My question:**

Should I report it as a *bug* to MySQL or does anybody know how to remove this warning?

**Update:**

Because a comment mentioned I should play with the arguments in `mysql_library_init()` I updated the question to a more compact/minimal working example.

**Update:**

This warning appears while the link process! The compilation works fine.

Comment: Sorry, I posted an invalid link. :-(

Comment: It seems a [gcc matter ](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51744). What is your [tag:gcc] version?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11402456/3436922) as reference.

Comment: OK, [This is you issue](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53568), I hope.

Comment: http://antirez.com/misc/lcov-html/usr/include/bits/string3.h.gcov.html at line 19 has code about this. It appears that you don't use string3.h directly so I suggest playing with the arguments to `mysql_library_init()`

Comment: (in /usr/include/bits/string3.h) :  `#ifndef _STRING_H
# error "Never use <bits/string3.h> directly; include <string.h> instead."
#endif` Maybe you or somebody else forgot to include string.h ?

Comment: Did you check the string3.h header file? It **is** the cause of the error message.